# Make a SAMBA file system visible to all users with mount_smbfs

Tags: mac-osx-server, server-message-block

We have a Macintosh OS10.6 server and a big storage system accessible via SMB.

Right now we can mount partitions, but when we mount them they are only accessible to the user that did the mount. All other users get "Access Denied."

It there any straightforward way to mount so that all users will be able to access the files? (We want all users mapped to a single SMB UID.)

Comment: What's the client OS?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I believe he's stating that he's mounting the SMB shares *on the Mac OS 10.6 server*, to make them available to all users of the OS X 10.6 server.

Comment: So then is the SMB server a *nix machine running Samba?

Comment: @Ignacio, Yes, Mac OS X is Unix based. You can think of it as being roughly FreeBSD-like, with some things pulled from other *BSDs, and plenty of Apple additions and modifications. And yes, the SMB server for Mac OS X, in both the client and Server distributions of Mac OS X, is Samba. The SMB client in both distributions is based on Boris Popov's smbfs from FreeBSD.

Comment: @vy32, I'd like to point out that if the clients are Macs and the server is a Mac, the best practice is to use AFP rather than SMB. Since AFP grew up with Mac OS, the filesystem semantics it provides map better to operations Mac OS X needs to do. ("Better" compared to SMB or NFS or WebDAV or any other remote filesystem mounting protocol.) There should be no problem sharing the same sharepoints via both AFP and SMB, which is common when you want to support both Mac and non-Mac clients.

Comment: @Spiff: So you're saying that the client machine is OS X, and the server machine is OS X? How did you deduce this?

Comment: @Ignacio, when I mentioned to you that the SMB client in Mac OS X is Popov's smbfs, I wasn't saying that that's what vy32 was using, I was just mentioning it for your information. However, I do think it's likely that vy32 is running Macs as his client machines, because Macs are the most common machines that have a "mount_smbfs" command (I could be wrong, but I don't believe that either Linux or Windows use that command; it's just the BSDs, and Mac OS X is the most common client BSD).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but the client is MacOS and the Server is running Solaris. (It's actually a $150,000 hierarchical storage management system with a Solaris front-end.) The server is also running Samba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mount_smbfs man page, it lists the answer.  Do what Josh recommended, but use the following command instead:

```
sudo mount_smbfs -f0777 -d0777 //user@server/sharename /Volumes/Share\ Name\ Here
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mounting the share as the root user? In the terminal, try:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/Share\ Name\ Here
sudo mount -t smbfs //user@server/sharename /Volumes/Share\ Name\ Here
```

For more information see: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20020610225855377

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. The files on the remote share are visible to the root user but not to other users.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/Volumes/Share\ Name\ Here`? What if you do `sudo chmod 777 /Volumes/Share\ Name\ Here` before `sudo mount...`?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I tried that, it doesn't work. Something in the OS is blocking UIDs other than the one that does the mount.